How to get the pool balance and pool token balance in past epoch
Is there a way to read pool balance and pool token balance in past epoch?(for given pool public key)

There is not a way you can check via RPC calls on Solana nodes (https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http). You need to find this type of information "somehow offchain".
I would think about approaches like

downloading snapshot (https://gist.github.com/mybluelotus/2ff5e9fd901ec1cb59d8fa24f115b857) with a slot from the epoch you search for. I believe the solana-snapshot-finder (https://github.com/c29r3/solana-snapshot-finder/tree/main) can help here to find if such snapshot is available to be downloaded. Only few past snapshots are stored by validators and only those available can be downloaded. When you have snapshot you can then use tool like solana-ledger-tool to get info about accounts (How to get accounts data from solana snapshot file?)
using some indexer and check their API. I mean to check from explorers https://explorer.solana.com/ , https://solscan.io/, https://solana.fm/
using Google BigQuery to work with onchain data (https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bigquery-public-data/crypto-solana-mainnet-us?project=crucial-oven-271922). Google should index historical Solana blockchain data and that can be queried

